# How can i refrence variable inside outer class (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

How can i reference the SongName variable in my other object? I am building my first app with Kotlin so I am really beginner.

````
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        SpotifyService.connect(this) {
            spotifyAppRemote?.let {
                it.playerApi.subscribeToPlayerState().setEventCallback {
                    val track: Track = it.track
                    Log.d("MainActivity", track.name + " by " + track.artist.name)
                    ALabel.text = track.name
                    Blabel.text = track.artist.name
                    var SongName = track.name
                    var SongArtist = track.artist.name
                }
            }
        }
        GeniusApi.PrintSomething()
    }
}``` ```object GeniusApi {
    val BASE_URL = "https://api.genius.com"
    val SEARCH_URL = BASE_URL + "/search"
    var DATA = SongName@MainActivity

    fun PrintSomething() {
        Log.e("GeniusApi", DATA)
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

On your Kotlin file you will need to place any functions or variables inside a

```
Companion Object {

lateinit var myobject

}
```

And then reference it like

```
TheObject.Companion.myobject
```